# Replacing string value

Tags: apex, force.com, sales-cloud

I want to replace the value of a string. This is an integer but saved in string. Eg: i am getting the value as 123.345 the i need to get the value as 123 only. I want to replace value after . with '' but the issue is i don't know how many decimal place is coming after point. 
Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
String myString = '123.123435';
String st = myString.substring(0, myString.indexOf('.') );
System.debug(st);
```

Answer (score 3):

One easy way is to convert it first into a decimal number and then convert the decimal into an integer.

```
String myString = '123.123435';
Decimal myDecimal = Decimal.valueOf(myString);
Integer myInteger = Integer.valueOf(myDecimal);
System.debug(myInteger);
```